# Switching between screens on a click

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-widget

i am creating an application with a listview and what i want to happen is when you choose an item from the listview the application will automatically move you to the next screen. Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: How do you have the next screen defined? Is it an activity? Is it a view?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) of your ListView. then you can use [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) to skip to the next screen/activity.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findeViewById(...);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg3) {
                // index = the index of the clicked element in the listview
                // create an intent and add index to its data
                startActivity(intent);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..it will helpful for u..

"list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClass(nextScreen.this,profile_details.class);
            intent.putExtra("profile", mArray.get(mPosition));
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);


        }
    });"
```

use this code.....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) and use startActivity() to bring up a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

For listening the list item click events you need to override onItemClickListener method .

See here :

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
        //If you want to pass parameters/values to NextActivity use putExtra
        intent.putExtra("my_data","my_values");
        startActivity(intent);


    }
});
```